# Can not get inline elements to work correctly with CSS

Tags: html, css

Let me start by saying I am somewhat new to CSS and html, but this project requires it so I am trying my best. I am having serious issues across the entirety of my page getting inline elements to work. I am going to post my code for 3 seperate section. I would like all three of them across the top of the page. The header 1 and 2 in the center, header 3 to the left, and the three textboxes to the right. I know I could use fixed positioning, but that does not adjust to various screen sizes and I would like to do it properly. Any and all advice would be appreciated as well as fixing it if possible. The container class is more or less a box i tried to create to hold all three of the elements I want on the same line. 
I will start with the CSS code

```
h1, h3 {
font-family: "Times New Roman";
     font-size: 30px;
}
h2 {

    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    float: left;
    padding:0;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
     font-size: 20px;
}
.textbox3 {
float: right;
    background: yellow;
     border: 3px double #848484; 
    outline:0; 
     font-size: 35px;
     text-align: center;
    height:100px; 
    width: 170px;

}
.textbox2 {
    float: right;
    background: yellow;
     border: 3px double #848484; 
    outline:0; 
     font-size: 35px;
     text-align: center;
    height:100px; 
    width: 170px;


}
.textbox1 {
    float: right; background: yellow; border: 3px double #848484; outline:0; font-size: 35px;text-align: center;
    height:100px; width: 170px; 
}
.container{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width:100%;
    background: #F5F5DC;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

// This is the html and php

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('EST'); ?> 
<div class="container">
<h1><center> <strong> words </center> </strong></h1>
<h3><center><?php echo date ('l, F j   h:i:s'); ?> </center> </h3> 


<h2>
<?php echo 'wrod:'   ?> <br>
<?php echo 'words:'; ?> <br>
<?php echo ' Time:'; ?> <br>
<?php echo ' Hour:'; ?> <br>
<?php echo '# :'; ?>  </h2>

<input class="textbox1" value="LF1: <?php echo $Element1; ?>"> 
<input class="textbox2"value="LF2: <?php echo $Element2; ?>"> 
 <input class="textbox3" value="LF3: <?php echo $Element3; ?>">  
 </div>
```

// Here is the table CSS

```
.Table1 { background-color:white;border-collapse:collapse ;width:33%; position: relative;}
.Table1 th { background-color:white;color:red; }
.Table1 td, .OilTable th { padding:3px;border:3px solid red; }

.Table2 { background-color:#eee;border-collapse:collapse; width:33%; position: relative;}
.Table2 th { background-color:white;color:black;width:20%; }
.Table2 td, .IronTable th { padding:3px;border:3px solid black; }
```

//Here is the table HTML

```
<table class="Table2";>
<tr>
<th height ="32" align="center">3 </th>
<td height ="32" align="center">4</td>
<th height ="32" align="center">3 </th>
<td height ="32" align="center">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th height ="32" align="center">3 </th>
<td height ="32" align="center">4</td>
<th height ="32" align="center">3 </th>
<td height ="32" align="center">4</td>
</tr>

<table class="Table1";>
<tr>
<th height ="32" align="center">1 </th>
<td height ="32" align="center">2</td>
<th height ="32" align="center">1 </th>
<td height ="32" align="center">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th height ="32" align="center">1 </th>
<td height ="32" align="center">2</td>
<th height ="32" align="center">1 </th>
<td height ="32" align="center">2</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Elements `h1...h6` are not `inline` elements, they are block elements.  The `float: left` doesn't do _anything_ if you position the element absolutely.  If you want the other two headers centered, you should use something like `text-align: center` if you want them stacked, otherwise wrap them in a container, set the display like `display: inline-block;`, and then position it however works best for you (e.g. using a `position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left -(1/2 element width)px;` combo.

Comment: Also `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: can you post an image of your desired result?

Comment: Can you post a blueprint of the layout with MSpaint or something?
There are better ways to do what you want so it's better if you gave us a picture of the layout you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Josh. I already decided to no longer use position  absolute on most elements because of screen resizing and such. However I am relativly new to CSS and am rather confused about your position and container statement you were talking about. I believe i already have them in a container. Could you please explain more or show a piece of code to demonstrate? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here is the crude drawing i made as far as layout   http://tinypic.com/r/24kwdh0/8

Comment: @user3072210 I read "cute" instead of "crude" until I read it twice a few minutes later ha

Answer (score 0):

The html was not connected to the css. Please connect the 2 files by doing the style tag.

Comment: They are connected. Sorry I didnt include that, thought it was assumed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this is by wrapping each section in its own container like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="left">
  <h2>
    wrod:  <br/>
    words: <br/>
    Time   <br/>
    Hour:  <br/>
    # :    
  </h2>
</div>

<div class="center">
    <h1><strong> words </strong></h1>
    <h3>DATE</h3> 
</div>



<div class="right">
    <input class="textbox1" value="LF1: "/> 
    <input class="textbox2"value="LF2: "/> 
    <input class="textbox3" value="LF3: "/>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.left{
    float: left;
    width: 20%; //whatever works
}

.center{
    float: left;
    width: 20%; //whatever works    
}

.right{
    float: left;
    width: 60%; //whatever works    
}

h1, h3 {
   font-family: "Times New Roman";
   font-size: 30px;
   display: inline-block; //add if you want these two on the same line
}


input { //since all of them are the same you can just target 'input'
    float: right;
    background: yellow;
    border: 3px double #848484; 
    outline:0; 
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    height:100px; 
    width: 120px; //I changed your width for my demo, it was rather large though

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vL51bp99/)

Comment: Ok Ok this is great. Been stuck on this for so long. Now two questions for you. The first thing you did in your CSS the html, body{} what was its purpose? And secondally I want to have more things down the page in a row clearly. I understand now i need to continue using divs to make my width sections for elements, but should i use <br> to seperate them in terms of height?

Comment: `html, body` was to clear the default margin that gets added to the document, and to set the width to 100% since I used percentages in my example.  Remove the margin and you can see the spacing around the edges. divs will fall after one another by nature, just make sure you clear elements that are being floated.

Comment: @user3072210 You should use `<p>` to separate text not `<br>`. Attach a class to `<p>`'s to style it rather than using `<br>` or `<h1>`, `<h2>` etc everywhere. Plus it's more reusable (purpose of CSS after all). Check out the other answer I gave to see what I mean, it should be more clear to see what's going on.

Comment: I think I have the text part figured out. I want to do the same thing with tables on the same line. I tried a similar setup to what you did above with the tables except not using div obviously since they are tables, however it did not work at all. Any ideas. Just two tables on the same line. Underneath the first row of text up above.

Comment: @user3072210 can you post an example?

Comment: @user3072210 the simple answer is you shouldnt be using tables for anything that listing tabular-data, so like a spreadhseet or a list, other than that you should be using something else like `div`s

Comment: @user3072210 I added the other layout you wanted on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the correct layout?

## [Code Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fgovsh2o/3/)

## [Full Screen Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fgovsh2o/3/embedded/result/)

CSS:

```
.container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px black solid;
}

.middle
{
    text-align: center;
}

.box
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px red solid;
}

.input-container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.user-input
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    <p>wrod:</p>
    <p>words: </p>
    <p>Time: </p>
    <p>Hour: </p> 
    <p># :<p/>
    </div>
        <div class="box middle"><h1>words</h1><h3>Date</h3></div>
    <div class="box input-container"><input class="user-input" value="textbox"><input class="user-input" value="textbox"><input class="user-input" value="textbox"></div>
</div>
```

Like @jmore009 said. Use tables for tabular data.

Here's the other layout that you want I believe.

## [Your other example](http://jsfiddle.net/z0421g93/5/)

CSS:

```
.number-collection-container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
}

.number-container
{
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
}

.right
{
    border: 3px black solid;
}

.content
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.red
{
    color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="number-collection-container">

<div class="collection">
<div class="number-container">
    <div class="content"><span class="text">3</span></div>
<div class="content right"><span class="text">4</span></div>
</div>
<div class="number-container">
<div class="content"><span class="text">3</span></div>
<div class="content right"><span class="text">4</span></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="collection">
<div class="number-container">
<div class="content"><span class="text">3</span></div>
<div class="content right"><span class="text">4</span></div>
</div>
<div class="number-container">
<div class="content"><span class="text">3</span></div>
<div class="content right"><span class="text">4</span></div>
</div>
</div>
    
<div class="collection red">
<div class="number-container">
<div class="content"><span class="text">1</span></div>
<div class="content right"><span class="text">2</span></div>
</div>
<div class="number-container">
<div class="content"><span class="text"></span>1</div>
<div class="content right"><span class="text">2</span></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="collection red">
<div class="number-container">
<div class="content"><span class="text">1</span></div>
<div class="content right"><span class="text">2</span></div>
</div>
<div class="number-container">
<div class="content"><span class="text">2</span></div>
<div class="content right"><span class="text">2</span></div>
</div>
</div>    
    
</div>
```